# How to use graphiql-explorer with express-graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql, graphiql

I ran the express-graphql by this code.

```
var { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};

var app = express();
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at http://localhost:4000/graphql');
```

but it only has Prettify, Merge, Copy, History toolbar.
I want to add Explorer toolbar using graphiql-explorer library
Is there a way to do that?

This is the current running screen.
[image]

And want like this.
[image]

Comment: The "graphiql" option can take an object as well as just true, so it's possible to configure it that way. Not sure it applies in your case, but I was able to add the headers editor with `graphiql:{headerEditorEnabled:true}`.